# Alt-Tab alternative for Windows 7 similar to linux mint

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, alt-tab

Is there an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> alternative for Windows 7. That works something like the one in Linux Mint. Wherein you can choose the way you switch applications. 
In Linux Mint. If you have already tried it.
I've already tried Vista Switcher and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> thingy. Do you know of other apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're thinking of is Simple CompizConfig Settings Manager. It's a truly awesome piece of software.

However, there's not too much of a Windows counterpart. I found one on Google, but of course, it was an April Fools' Joke. Compiz is *the* most configurable window manager out there, so it's pretty hard to port. About as close as you'll get is using Windows+Tab, which counterparts the "Flip" option, and Alt+Tab, which you already know is the "Static Switcher".

You may also be interested in [DExpose2](https://sites.google.com/site/devrexster/dexpose2), which is a counterpart of Scale for Compiz. I used to use this before I upgraded my setup, and it's really slick.

In summary: you probably will never get that option in Windows, Windows+Tab is superslick, and I loved Dexpose2.